# Need to update Current version of FROM_DT to previous version TO_DATE for same table

Tags: sql, oracle

Requirement is like below: In the same table i need as below expected output.
Table name: TAB
Current Output:

```
PRIM_KEY| FROM_DT  |  TO_DT
11111     01-JAN-00   01-JAN-25
11112     01-MAR-16   01-JAN-25
```

Expecting Output:

```
PRIM_KEY| FROM_DT  |  TO_DT
11111     01-JAN-00   01-MAR-16
11112     01-MAR-16   01-JAN-25
```

Comment: What is the logic behind? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: You seem to be saying that you want the FROM_DT to be set to the TO_DT of the previous record but that is not what your expected output shows. Instead you show the TO_DT of the first record as being set to the FROM_DT of the second.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function and focus only on row following,the last row will be null you can skip that.

```
MERGE
 INTO table1 AS A
 USING 
     (
    SELECT PRIM_KEY, FROM_DT, MIN(FROM_DT) OVER ( PARTITION BY 1 ORDER   BY  PRIM_KEY  ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS NEXT_START_DT
    FROM table1) AS B
    ON A.PRIM_KEY = B.PRIM_KEY AND B. PRIM_KEY IS NOT NULL
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET TO_DT = NEXT_START_DT;
```